# Date formate change when post to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to get 31-12-2015 Date formate into my controller. but in my case when  i try to post my date from view to contoller that time in debug mode it show me mm-dd-yyyy(12-31-2015) now how to get my formate.

e.g when i enter this below date

1) 12-30-2016 i get into my controller

2) 30-12-2016 i dont get date into my controller.

Model

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Date")]
[DisplayName("Payment Date")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/mm/yyyy}")]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

View

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date,new { @class = "k-input datepickerbootstrap", @required = "required", @id = "Date", @name = "Date" })
```

Javascript

```
$('.datepickerbootstrap').datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
        });
```

Comment: The change the culture of your server to one that accepts dates in the format `dd/MM/yyyy` (and remove `new { @name = "Date" }` -  the `name` attribute is already `name="Date"` but it does not work so its pointless anyway)

Comment: What do you mean by "it show me"? Do you understand that a `DateTime` value doesn't *have* a format? Formats are only applied when you parse from a string or format to a string. The debugger is just showing you the default culture representation. Additionally, you've set your date format in C# to use slashes (or rather, the culture-specific month separator) but you're using dashes in the Javascript. Finally, you're using `mm` when you should be using `MM`, at least in the C#. (Check for the Javascript too.)

Comment: i already try to remove new {@name} but nothing happen but i try to add calture of date formate

Comment: jon skeet i already try mm and also MM but nothing happen

Comment: Well you shouldn't just be trying them at random. You should *definitely* be using `MM` in the C# code, and you should check the documentation for what to use in the date picker. But then there are all the other problems I pointed out...

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are using `en-US` culture which uses `MM/dd/yyyy` date format. You need to change the server culture to one that uses `dd/MM/yyyy` format (for example `en-GB`)

You may do it through web config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <globalization uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**EDIT**

As Stephen pointed out in his comment the format that is used in datepicker configuration has to match the format that is defined by server culture so
if we take `en-GB` culture as an example since it's date format is `dd/MM/yyyy`, datepicker format has to be the same:

```
$('.datepickerbootstrap').datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        });
```

Comment: The OP is specifying the date format in an attribute. It shouldn't be taking the default when parsing.

Comment: @JonSkeet, That's ignored in OP's case because he is using a datepicker plugin (its only relevant when using `@Html.EditorFor()` in the view (with no plugin) to generate the browser's implementation of a datepicker

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Ah - in that case, that sounds like the most important thing to talk about in an answer :)

Comment: Alex, You should probably also note that if you changing the culture to one that is `dd/MM/yyyy`, then the datepicker configuration should be `dd/mm/yyyy` (i.e. the same date separator)